# How to use `adb shell screenrecord --output-format=h264` together with VLC

Tags: terminal, streaming, vlc

I am trying to set up a live stream showing the screen of my Android phone. When I tried

```
adb shell screenrecord --output-format=h264 | /Applications/vlc.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC
```

VLC will start but there will be no content. How do I do this properly?

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command `adb shell screenrecord --output-format=h264`
is missing a `-` at the end.
It should be

```
adb shell screenrecord --output-format=h264 - | /Applications/vlc.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -
```